# How to use google mobile vision for iOS with carthage

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, google-vision, carthage

I got working project with pods, but I want to support Carthage as well. One of the dependencies is google mobile vision, that is available at cocoapods. I can't find github repo for this, only the samples provided by google. How can I support this framework via Carthage? Thanks for answers.

Comment: Source for the latest version is here: https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/c07e7414883cfd61/GoogleMobileVision-1.5.0.tar.gz

It's listed in the Podspec: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/861301e2f08929f6685adf40b595da4a372d926f/Specs/0/4/2/GoogleMobileVision/1.5.0/GoogleMobileVision.podspec.json#L151

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but a binary version of GoogleMobileVision is included with the [experimental Firebase Carthage distribution](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md).

GoogleMobileVision will be downloaded if you add the following to the Cartfile:

```
binary "https://dl.google.com/dl/firebase/ios/carthage/FirebaseMLVisionBinary.json"
```

Comment: Another problem is that Google SDKs have issue with signing. There is option in build phases Embed framworks Code sign on Copy, but that add the framework inside emebedded frameworks in general tab and error could not inspect application package appears. How can I solve that?

Comment: Great it solves part of the problem. This does not contain TextDetector or any other detector you would want to use. If I include TextDetector downloaded from podspec link, there is no plist file and there is issue mentioned above.